# Display Error if Number System input is invalid

Tags: java, binary, hex, octal

I want to code the Number System to ASCII converter using Java (which I already tried) 
But I want to output "Invalid" if ever the input is wrong instead of exiting the program and showing an error. Hope it's possible.

I already get the converted outputs. I just want to put an "Invalid" output in case my selected number system and input don't match.

```
  do{
        opt=displayMainMenu();

        switch(opt){
            case 1: 
                    binary=getBinary();
                    System.out.println("\n\tASCII Character: "+ (char)binary);
                    in.readLine();
                    break;

            case 2: 
                    octal=getOctal();
                    System.out.println("\n\tASCII Character: "+(char)octal);
                    in.readLine();
                    break;

            case 3:
                    decimal=getDecimal();
                    System.out.println("\n\tASCII Character: "+(char)decimal);
                    in.readLine();
                    break;
            //case 4: still don't have Hexadecimal since I find it difficult. Sorry  
            case 5: 
                    System.out.println("\f\n\tGood Bye!");
                    break;

            default: 
                    System.out.print("\n\tInvalid Option.");
                    in.readLine();   
        }


    }while(opt!=5);
```

//I'll just post one

```
          public static int getOctal() throws Exception{
          BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);   
    System.out.println("\f\n\t\t- Octal -\n");

    System.out.print("\n\tInput Octal Number:  ");
    String n=s.nextLine();

    int oct = Integer.parseInt(n,8);
    return oct;
}
```

Sample Input:

Choose a Number System: 2  //Octal to ASCII

Input Octal Number: 3A //which is Hexadecimal

Output: Invalid.

Choose a Number System: 2  //Octal to ASCII

Input Octal Number: 041//which is correct

Output: ASCII is !

Comment: Why don't you wrap the code block in a 'while (true)' statement? After printing Invalid, it will as again for input and go on.

Comment: Yes, I am using a while loop statement. But I want to know if its possible to check if a Number System input is valid to the case I selected. I mean. What if I selected Case 2(Octal) but then inputs "0100010" (yet it's not even an octal number). Sorry for being so messy :/

Answer (score 1):

If you ask me, I think your **getOctal()** method should really be called **getIntegerFromOctal()**. But hey...maybe that's just me.

What a lot of people do is wrap the parsing within a **try/catch** block and trap any errors, something like this:

```
public static int getIntegerFromOctal() {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    String ls = System.lineSeparator();

    System.out.println(ls + "    - Octal -");
    while (true) {
        System.out.print("Input Octal Number:  ");
        String n = s.nextLine();
        int oct = 0;
        try {
            oct = Integer.parseInt(n, 8);
            return oct;
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            System.err.print("Invalid Octal Value Supplied! Try again..." + ls + ls);
        }
    }
}
```

Another way this can be done is by using a [Regular Expression](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) (RegEx) in conjunction with the [String#matches()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_matches.htm) method:

```
public static int getIntegerFromOctal() {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    String ls = System.lineSeparator();

    System.out.println(ls + "    - Octal -");
    while (true) {
        System.out.print("Input Octal Number:  ");
        String n = s.nextLine();
        int oct = 0;
        /* The String#matches() method is used here with a
           regex that ensures that only digits from 0 to 7 
           (octal digits) are supplied. If you want to also
           ensure Integer Literal where the integer value
           supplied starts with a 0 then use: "^0[0-7]+$" */
        if (!n.matches("^[0-7]+$")) {
            System.err.print("Invalid Octal Value (" + n + ") Supplied! Try again..." + ls + ls);
            continue;
        }
        oct = Integer.parseInt(n, 8);
        return oct;
    }     
}
```